# Straighten handwriting text line using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have images of text lines, where some lines are not straight.
As a preprocessing step before text recognition, I'd like to straighten the images, so text appears horizontal.
How to achieve this in OpenCV with Python?

An example of text line:
[image]

Comment: get boxes for glyphs/words, associate them roughly horizontally to form a line. then estimate the "baseline" for that line (imagined line on which someone would have written the text), and use that. that's just one thing I would try without knowing the state of the art. you should do literature research (find papers).

Comment: See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by analysing the image in the frequency domain. I am attaching a link below. Read the blog for best explanation on this topic. Orientation of text is also added as an example in the blog.

[https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/fourier.htm#:~:text=The%20Fourier%20Transform%20is%20an,is%20the%20spatial%20domain%20equivalent](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/fourier.htm#:%7E:text=The%20Fourier%20Transform%20is%20an,is%20the%20spatial%20domain%20equivalent)